# double array in cell, how to indexing?

Tags: matlab

I have an cell including array as below format

```
a{x,y,z}(i,j)
```

a is 3 dimensional cell
and
each cell have i*j array

```
a <79x95x68 cell>
val(:,:,1) = 

Columns 1 through 2

[6x6 double]    [6x6 double]
[6x6 double]    [6x6 double]
[6x6 double]    [6x6 double]
```

i want to rearrange that as below format

```
a{i,j}(x,y,z)
```

how to? any good idea? i have to do iteration?

matlab say, a{:,:}(x,y,z) is bad cell referencing.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a suboptimal way to go, it isn't memory efficient, but it is pretty straightforward:
say that `x=79`,`y=95`,`z=68` are the dimensions of your original cell array, and that each of them gives the same dimensionality  `ixj` matrix (6 by 6). So first you can make a matrix out of the cell array:

```
b=horzcat(a{:});
```

then we can reshape it to a 5-d array (this is just for pedagogical purposes) so you already have it ordered as (i,j,x,y,z)...

```
c=reshape(b,6,6,x,y,z);
```

then you can either work with `c(i,j,x,y,z)`, or assign `c` to a cellarray:

```
d=cell(6,6);

for i=1:6
    for j=1:6
        d{i,j}=squeeze(c(i,j,:,:,:));
    end
end
```